# Why is xlink used with an svg instead of just using an image tag?

Tags: svg

I was just told to replace an img tag with an svg image to an svg tag with a use tag and it is showing the image in the wrong color now and broke the css (it needs a relative position that is pretty darn strange).  Why use the svg tag with xlink?  what do we gain from using svg tag with xlink?

```
<img class='my-image' src='blah.svg' />
```

is the original code.

```
<svg class='my-image'>
    <use xlink:href='#blah'></use>
</svg>
```

is the new code.  It changed the color of the image and wrecked the css, but it did display the image.

Comment: Please show us the code you used for both variants, and at least a skeleton of the SVG itself. And what has "x-path" got to do with anything?

Comment: @ccprog sorry the question said x-path but I meant xlink.  its corrected along with the code samples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one (`<img>`) refers to an external file. The whole file is displayed as it is, with no opportunity to restyle it.

The second variant lets you include the SVG in your page, and then use individual pieces of it throught your page.  So you could include an SVG with a dozen icon definitions. Then use those icons on different parts of the page.  You can also restyle the icons with CSS if you want.

Comment: well CSS did work at least to resize and position it when it was an image, but your point is well made about using the second method and getting just a piece of it.  I have seen icons done that way and now I understand better what I was looking at.